# Any shortcut to copy a file to the same filename + different ext?

Tags: linux, shell

In linux shell, you can make a backup like this

```
cp f1.js f1.js.bkup
```

Any shortcuts i can do ? e.g.

```
cp f1.js *.bkup
```

Comment: Do it via function: `bkup() { cp "$1" "$1.bkup"; }` and then `bkup f1.js`

Comment: i don't want to create a shell script just for this.

Comment: This is not shell script. This function goes in `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Or on the command line itself: `f=f1.js ; cp $f $f.bkup`